# How to use `vi` when you've never used it before?

Tags: server, minecraft, vi

I'm using Ubuntu server edition to host a minecraft server, and I needed to changed the server properties, after using the command vi server.properties, I made the required change, but can't save them, and I'm at a lose at this point as to how to save?

Comment: How you are saving the file and what error you are getting?

Comment: Use 'ESC' to exit from edit mode then type ':wq!'

Answer (score 4):

Run the command `vimtutor` to learn a lot of the many cool functions of vim.

If you just want to do very basic things here is a little cheat sheet:

Pressing **i** in normal mode allows you to insert text. You can usuallu get into normal mode by pressing the `Esc` key.

Entering **:w** will write or **save** your edits.

Entering **:q** will quit the application.

To save time, entering **:wq** will **write and quit**.

I highly recommend to run the `vimtutor` command to see some of the power of vim.

Good luck on your Minecraft Server!

Answer (score 1):

:-)  **If you don't use `vi` on a daily basis, wherever you see `vi`, *it's safe to replace it by `nano`.***  Both are terminal text editors and `nano` is just a little bit easier to use then `vi`.

Screenshot of `nano /etc/host.conf`

[image: Screenshot of nano]

As you can see, the lower 2 lines contain the most used commands and even a built-in help system.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to go to the help page.
Everything will be much easier from that point onwards...

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: That being said, if you *really* want to use `vi`, type `man vi` and start reading...  It's an extremely efficient editor if you use it minimum 8 hours/day!